# Big Theta problem

Tags: big-o

I have two functions:

- f(n) = 2;
- g(n) = 10 ^ 100;

I have to justify if f(n) = BigTheta(g(n)) or not.

My guess is that f(n) is BigTheta(g(n)), since both functions are constants (wich means the functions are proportional), but a my teacher insists that I am wrong.

Am I right? Is there any way I could rest my case? 
Sorry if this sounds like a noob question! Thanks.

Comment: It is not a homework, it's a part of my exam.

Comment: On the site here, the `homework` tag tends to encompass actual homework, exams, etc... generally anything school-related ought to be tagged with `homework`. Aside from that being a central way to unify a type of question, it's also pragmatic: if you look at the tags, you'll see that `homework` has almost 900 followers and almost 9000 questions, whereas `exam` has only one follower and about 100 questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f(n) <= g(n) * 1
2    <= 10^100     for all n >= 0
```

Thus `f(n) = O(g(n))`.

```
f(n) >= g(n) * 2/(10^100)
2    >= 10^100 * 2/(10^100) = 2      for all n >= 0
```

And so `f(n) = Ω(g(n))`.

Both `f(n)=O(g(n))` and `f(n)=Ω(g(n))` imply `f(n) = Θ(g(n))`. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. Assuming you quoted the problem correct and there's no misunderstanding, your teacher is wrong if they said they are not theta-of-each-other.

Here's the definition:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Clearly `|100^10|*k1 <= |2| <= |100^2|*k2` for constants `k1=1/100^10` and `k2=1` (for all x larger than any suitable cutoff value `x_cutoff`)

Without knowing the actual text of the exam problem though, and the exact text you wrote (or circled), there is no way we on the internet can know there isn't some sort of misreading of the problem. You should also note that you could still be wrong in your justification even though your answer is right.

For the record, not only is `f(x)` in the set `BigTheta(g(x))`, but `g(x)` is in the set `BigTheta(f(x))`. I think an equivalent definition is that **the ratio of the two functions is bounded as `x -> infinity`** (follows by dividing the Wikipedia definition by `|g(x)|` to get `|f(x)|/|g(x)| < constant` past some cutoff point), which may be an easier definition to think about (and more obvious to prove). It would also imply that BigTheta is a symmetric relation.

You now have the suitable tools to ask "why do you think I am wrong?" and then use math to determine which of you two are right; any misunderstanding should appear in the math, if not you'll have proved your point.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is the exact text, only translated from my language into English. It is not the justification that bothers him, but the answer.